# Why can't I define a function within the main function in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This program works fine if I implement function prototyping and define this after the main function.
Why is it like that?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef unsigned short UShort;

main()
{
    UShort length, breadth, TotalArea;
    cout<<"Enter length and breadth";
    cin>>length>>breadth;

    UShort FindArea(UShort l, UShort b)
    {
    return l * b;
    }

    TotalArea = FindArea(length, breadth);
    cout<<"Total Area is "<<TotalArea;
}
```

Comment: I guess one could provide some historical explanation how C was developed and it was difficult to implement or something like that, but there's really no better answer than "the standard says so".

Comment: C++ does not allow defining a function within a function.  You could use a lambda instead.

Comment: Probably the answer by "Jerry Coffin" comes closest to answering your question: [why wasn't the idea of nested functions, implemented in older c++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399896/why-wasnt-the-idea-of-nested-functions-implemented-in-older-c-standard)

Comment: `main` must have the explicit return type `int`. C++ does not support implicit return type `int` when no return type is defines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is it like that?

Because the standard says so.

And you don't need it, because you can define a type inside a function:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef unsigned short UShort;

int main()
{
    UShort length, breadth, TotalArea;
    cout<<"Enter length and breadth";
    cin>>length>>breadth;

    struct FindAreaType {
        UShort operator()(UShort l, UShort b) const
        {
            return l * b;
        }
    };
    FindAreaType FindArea;            

    TotalArea = FindArea(length, breadth);
    cout<<"Total Area is "<<TotalArea;
}
```

A more convenient way to do more or less the same is a lambda expression:

```
auto FindArea = [](UShort l, UShort b) { return l * b; };
TotalArea = FindArea(lenght,breadth);
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve what you ask for is to use lambda instead of a function.

```
// ...

int main()
{
    // ...

    // Define lambda instead of a function
    auto FindArea = [](UShort l, UShort b) { return l * b; };

    // Use defined lambda
    TotalArea = FindArea(length, breadth);
    // ... 
}
```

As commenters have mentioned, due to historical reasons there are no embedded functions in C. But since C++11 there are now lambda expression.

Since C++17 you can even use `auto` keyword instead of explicit type for lambda parameters.

```
auto FindArea = [](auto l, auto b) { return l * b; };
```

This way you can use `FindArea` for `float` or `double` arguments (or anything with an overloaded multiplication operator).